# how to resolve lighthouse issue "Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy"

Tags: javascript, next.js, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

Hi as per the title i am trying to cache for SSR pages and below are the approach i've already tried but still getting issue in Lighthouse.
[Lighthouse Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Ce7.png)

`export const getServerSideProps = async context => { context.res.setHeader( 'Cache-Control', 'public, maxage=10, stale-while-revalidate=59' ) const baseProps = await basePageServerSide(context, ROUTES.HOMEPAGE); return baseProps }`

Please let me know if there are any other approach i can use to resolve this.

i tried caching using basepageServerSide

Answer (score 0):

`maxage=10` is only a 10 seconds cache policy.  Additionally, `stale-while-revalidate` means at most the object will spend 59 seconds in cache.  Lighthouse wants things to be cached for longer.  In my testing I have seen that Lighthouse wants a minimum of 1month.

Although, not ideal for HTML and other things, this should be sufficient for static objects (css, js, images, etc).